# Why would a QDialog not show when called?

Tags: qdialog

I am new to the whole QT things, so please bear with me :-)

I am working on a program that has a QMainWindow with a couple of menu options.  I then use QActions to call functions to do something with the menu options.

I have put together a QDialog, which shows when called directly, but not when called through the QAction dialog.

Code:

Constructor Code

```
View::View(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *topFiller = new QWidget;
    topFiller->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->setMargin(5);
    layout->addWidget(topFiller);
    setLayout(layout);

    createActions();
    createMenus();
    change();  //Works but displayed as a separate window

    QWidget::setWindowTitle( "Stock Editor");
    setMinimumSize(300, 300);
    resize(680, 520);

}
```

QAction Snippet

```
changeact = new QAction(tr("&Change"), this);
    connect(saveact, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(change()));
```

Change() Function

```
void View::change()
{
    QDialog *dialogWin = new QDialog(this);
    dialogWin->setWindowTitle("Add Item");

    QFormLayout *formLayout = new QFormLayout();

    QLineEdit *barcodeLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    QLabel *barcodeLabel = new QLabel("Barcode");
    QLineEdit *descLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    QLabel *descLabel = new QLabel("Description");
    QSpinBox *stockSpinBox = new QSpinBox;
    QLabel *stockLabel = new QLabel("Stock");
    QSpinBox *priceSpinBox = new QSpinBox;
    QLabel *priceLabel = new QLabel("Price");

    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok
                                         | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

   // connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
   // connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

    formLayout->addRow(barcodeLabel, barcodeLineEdit);
    formLayout->addRow(descLabel, descLineEdit);
    formLayout->addRow(stockLabel, stockSpinBox);
    formLayout->addRow(priceLabel, priceSpinBox);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(dialogWin);
    mainLayout->addLayout(formLayout);
    mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

    dialogWin->setLayout(mainLayout);
    dialogWin->activateWindow();
    dialogWin->show();

}
```

How can I get the box to appear on top of the Main Window when called?

Thanks for the assistance